# NAV2 - Gazebo does not load model

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I am running this tutorial https://navigation.ros.org/getting_started/index.html#installation
I am using ROS2 Foxy in Ubuntu 20.04 and Gazebo 9

I have exported the models as the tutorial explains:

```
 source /opt/ros/<ros2-distro>/setup.bash
export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=waffle
export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH:/opt/ros/<ros2-distro>/share/turtlebot3_gazebo/models
```

However, Gazebo is not loading:

[image: image description]

I should have this behavior at the end when setting a 2D goal pose to the robot:

https://navigation.ros.org/_images/navigation_with_recovery_behaviours.gif

But I am not having success in localizing the robot...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/412278/nav2---gazebo-does-not-load-model/) by [Vini71](https://answers.ros.org/users/37882/vini71/) on ROS Answers with karma: 266 on 2023-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you didn't fill in the ROS2 Distribution :-)

```
../<ros2-distro>/...
```

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2023-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vini71](https://answers.ros.org/users/37882/vini71/) on 2023-02-09**:
Hi Steve,

I fulfilled the export statement with "ros2-foxy" instead of "foxy".
In addition, I have installed additional pkg:

sudo apt-get install ros-foxy-turtlebot3-gazebo*
sudo apt-get install ros-foxy-robot-state-publisher*

Then it worked.
Steve, I checked **your podcast with Ricardo** and the NAV2 documentation.
I decided to use NAV2 for our research, which uses an autonomous truck for **off-road** monitoring applications. We were using Autoware.Universe, but we checked that it is "too much" for our simple scenario and decision-making needs. I checked that **NAV2 works for Ackermann** types, but **even for a big truck**?

I am also "afraid" about the localization pkg: The **NDT-MCL** localizer you mentioned on the podcast. We do have velodynes, but we're off-road, so we don't have a previous map with landmarks to match. Is this something impeditive to using NAV2 off-road?

What is **your consideration** in this regard? Do you have some success of-road cases to share a link?
Thanks